# Tree Parser support in Antlr3

Tags: c++, antlr3

The early version of Antlr3 for C++ doc says that the TreeParser is not supported. Is it supported now in newer releases of Antlr3 for C++?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's still not supported and probably will never be. ANTLR 4 is now the current version and C++ support is currently being developed for that.

Comment: Antlr4 has been here since 2013, and since then the C++ wrapper has been in development. Do you think it will come around at some point?

Comment: Well, this is frequently discussed in the antlr mailing list, but it looks like this will still take a while.